# I added a close function in my dialog-message to clear the content and close it, but when i try to open another one it won't open

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dialog

So I'm trying to open a dialog and when i close it i want the content of it to be cleared when i open another one. But the problem is when i try to close it, i can't open another one or the previous that i closed.

//this is the part when the dialog is opened.

```
$(function () {
        $("#dialog-message").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            height: 650,
            width: 1100,
            autoOpen: false,

            title: "Vehicle Detailed Movement Report",
            buttons: {

                Close : function () {
                    $("#dialog-message").html("");
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

            });
         });
```

//this is the part when i get the parameter and opens the dialog

```
function DisplayMovement(intime, outtime, minoption, plateno, user) {

document.getElementById("mappage").src = "Movementclass-ali.aspx?u=" 
user + "&p=" + plateno + "&r=&l=&bdt=" + intime + "&edt=" + outtime + 
"&m=" + minoption;
        document.getElementById("mappage").style.visibility = "visible";
        $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
    }
```

// this is my div

```
<div id="dialog-message"  title="" style="padding-top: 1px; padding- 
right: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px; font-size: 10px; padding-left: 0px; font- 
weight: bold; font-family: Myriad Pro,Lucida 
Grande,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; overflow:hidden;" >
        <iframe id="mappage" name="mappage" frameborder="0" 
scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%" style="visibility: hidden; 
border: solid 1px #aac6ff;" />
    </div>
```

I expect to clear the iframe when closed so when i try to open another one it won't show the previous loaded data before it change to new data.

Comment: Try to create  demo that reproduces problem. Have personally recycled the same dialog many many times with no issues. Is anything removing it? Any errors? Have you tried inspecting it in dev tools elements inspector?

Comment: No i don't see any errors, i even tried inspecting it in dev tools. But i still can't seem to find a solution for my problem